# Indefinite Consequent First Order Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Suppose I want to make the statement:

> For every index $i$ in the ordered Array $A$, $A[i]\leq A[i+1]$

Using first order logic I'd write it like:

> $\forall i($inRange$(i) \implies A[i]\leq A[i+1]) $

Which intuitively should be true under the interpretation where the universe is $\mathbb{N}$, inRange($i$) is a predicate that states that $0\leq i < size(A)-1$ and $A[i]$ is a function that returns the element in the $i$-th position of A.

However, this would be true iff for every $i$ in $ \mathbb{N}$, the formula:

> $ $inRange$(i) \implies A[i]\leq A[i+1] $

is true under the same interpretation. But if we have $j\in \mathbb{N}$, $j> size(A)$, then the formula

> $ $inRange$(j) \implies A[j]\leq A[j+1] $

would have an 'indefinite' consequent, since $A[j]$ is not defined. Should I consider it true just because the antecedent is false, or there is some special consideration to be taken?

Answer (score 0):

There're at least 3 ways to deal with your partial function extension problem:

1. formally using free logic (a variant of first order logic whose term can denote nothing).
2. using a total function to represent your partial function.
3. using a higher arity relation symbol to emulate your partial function.

I found this old [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845450/defining-a-partial-function-in-a-formal-theory) described all three approaches in detail already.

Comment: Thanks! So if I decide to stick to first order logic, I should define the function $A[i]$ as total somehow  (for example assigning 0 to out of range indexes). I guess it won't affect the result since if its out of range the antecedent is true so the implication is also true.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, if you read formal definitions of function symbol in any FOL textbook, it's defined as total (let me know if you found a counterexample) otherwise a wff containing the functional symbol won't have a definite truth value. If you choose approach #2/3 in my above answer to stick with FOL, then a false antecedent means the material implication is vacuously true which is also consistent with the non-vacuous case. unlike array out of bound error in programming, it cannot restrict your math total function or relation definition which is totally mental or in some real Platonic realm...

Answer (score 0):

> For every index $i$ in the ordered Array $A$, $A[i]\leq A[i+1]$

Hint: Somehow define a function $a:N\to A ~~~$ (not sure how you do this in FOL)

$\forall x: [x\in N \implies a(x)\leq a(x+1)]$