# Structures with partial functions

Tags: first-order-logic

Suppose, a FO language has two binary relation symbols $U_1, U_2$ and two binary function symbols $g_1, g_2.$ In each structure of this language, the function $g_1$ shall be defined only on pairs  $(x_1, x_2)$ where $U_1(x_1, x_2)$, and the function $g_2$ is defined only on $(x_1, x_2)$ where $U_2(x_1, x_2).$ Can there be structures with partial functions? How to describe them?

Comment: The usual semantics for first-order logic does not allow for partial functions. However, it's easy to either whip up a modified semantics which does (together with a sound-and-complete proof system for same), or simply replace each partial function with a corresponding *relation* (which is a bit hacky but does the job).

Comment: There was a recent similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4238285/indefinite-consequent-first-order-logic/4238344#4238344) about your concerns of partial functions in this site, hopefully it helps.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks. I may use ternary relations instead of functions: $G_1(x_1, x_2, x_3) \equiv (g_1(x_1, x_2) = x_3).$ If it is correct, it would solve it for me.

Comment: @Marina Yes, and you can actually add an axiom that the ternary relation $G_i$ is actually a partial function.

Comment: @Berci It may be like this: $$G(x, y, z) \& (z^\prime \neq z) \Rightarrow \lnot(G(x, y, z^\prime))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial functions could be presented as relations in structures. In fact, since constants are functions and functions are relations, sometimes we only have relation (predicate) symbols in first order languages which are called predicate languages. But since constants and functions have their own properties different from relations and we want to study objects in mathematical practice involving constants, functions and relations, in mathematical logic we usually put constant symbols and function symbols into the languages.